# Identify SSN from string in SAS

Tags: string, function, sas

I am trying to link two datasets using SSN. The first dataset is clean, and all SSN are presented in this format: xxx-xx-xxxx. In the second dataset, the SSN is a mess. Here are some examples of the SSNs in that dataset: *****1234; #111 PUC; 11111/123456789; TN# 123-45-6789; #123456789; PT #123-45-6789; DOE, JOHN #1; 1111111111111; 123-45-6789; 11/123-45-6789; 11-123-45-6789; 123-45-6789/123-45-6788; 11111/ 123456789; 11111/ 123-45-6789

I want to identify/extract 9 digit numbers (xxxxxxxxx or xxx-xx-xxxx) from the messy string.

I've used several different SAS functions (index, substr, compress, length) to specifically target the examples shown above, but was wondering if another strategy is available because I am afraid that I am missing some SSN because my programming is only targeting these more commonly used formats that I see. For example, not only is the following code clunky, but it only identifies SSNs in the xxx-xx-xxxx format (without a dash before the initial dash):

```
'''
    INDEX=INDEX(SSN,'-');
    START=INDEX-3;
    IF START <0 THEN START=.;
    SSN=SUBSTR(SSN,START,11);
    SSN2=COMPRESS(SSN,' */#-_','a');
    CHECK=LENGTH(SSN2);
    IF CHECK <9 THEN SSN2=''; 
'''
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See this paper, specifically Page 2 https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug07/ap/ap19.pdf

Comment: Probably want to use RegEx for this. Check out the `prxparse` function and `call prxsubstr` routine.

Comment: Thanks Reeza and Stu!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, everyone! Using your suggestions, this worked for me:

```
'''
data NEW;
   length SSN $11;
   re=prxparse('/(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})|(\d{9})/');
   set OLD;
   if prxmatch(re, ORIGINAL_SSN) then
      do;
         SSN=prxposn(re, 0, ORIGINAL_SSN);
         output;
      end;
run;
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression pattern `/\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}/` will detect most things SSN.  Real world data might have some oddball edge cases where SSN looking information is not SSN.

Among many regex things SAS can do are:

- filter via `PRXMATCH` function
- modify via `PRXCHANGE` function
- extract via `PRXPAREN`, `PRXPOSN`, or `PRXMATCH` & `SUBSTR` function

A more complex regex will detect **validly constructed** SSNs that are possibly valid.  (A conforming number that has never been assigned is invalid.)

From https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/poms.nsf/lnx/0110201035

> ... Also, identify invalid SSNs with:
> • The first three digits (former area number) as "000," "666,” or in the 900 series.
>
> • The second group of two digits (former group number) as "00."
>
> • The third group of four digits (former serial number) as "0000."

https://ihateregex.io/expr/ssn/ describes in great detail the operation of the complex pattern:

`^(?!0{3})(?!6{3})[0-8]\d{2}-?(?!0{2})\d{2}-?(?!0{4})\d{4}$`

*Note: I added meta character `?` after the dashes to allow for SSN that might not contain dashes*

Comment: And then I could use another regular expression pattern /\d{9}/ to detect the SSNs without dashes, correct? But what if the string has 10 digits in a row? Is there a way to flag that extraction? I guess I could do a 9 digit extraction and then do a 10 digit extraction to create a flag for that variable. Is that how you would approach this?

Comment: Or you could replace in the pattern the 'must have dash' `-` with a 'zero or one dash` `-?`

Comment: Oh, I see. How is that written?